# How do I bind a Border in Silverlight 4 XAML to a variable in my C# ViewModel code?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, mvvm, border

I know how to bind an attribute of a Silverlight XAML Border, Height for example, to a variable in my C# code. But how can I bind the Border item itself to a variable of type Border in my C# code?

Let's say that in my C# code (ViewModel, not code-behind), I have variable of type Border called myBorder. What I want to do is something like this in my XAML:

```
<Border Source="{Binding myBorder}"/>
```

But Source, Content, and so on are not attributes of the Border element that are available to be set, so how can I do this?

Comment: There is a reason why what you are trying to do isn't possible. Its bad MVVM design to have view specific information in the viewmodel. Why are you wanting to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Your XAML should be like the following

```
<Border Background="{Binding Path=Background}" DataContext="{Binding myBorder}" Height="{Binding Path=Height}" Width="{Binding Path=Width}"/>
```

in your vm

```
myBorder = new Border();
            myBorder.Height = 20;
            myBorder.Width = 30;
            myBorder.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

Remember that myBorder should be declared as a Property not a field

Comment: The ViewModel should not concern itself with border height, weight and color. That should be left to the View.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a ViewModel, I would gather that you are trying to follow the MVVM pattern. In that case, your ViewModel should hold the data that affects the border choice (a boolean value - like IsSelected - , an enumeration, etc.) and you should use a IValueConverter to achieve this. Your XAML would look like:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource BlueIfTrueRedIfFalseConverter}}"/>
```

For implementing your ValueConverter, see the following link: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx

This means that you now have separation of concerns. Your ViewModel need not concern itself on how it's going to be rendered, that is the View's job.